# Mathematics lessons online?

Tags: calculus, self-learning

IN school, I did not really care about my future, until I started working with computers, and getting into programming.

I'm doing computer science  at the moment & its currently really easy, but I heard that to do a degree in Computer science in the uni, I need a specific level of mathematics class.

Currently my math class is LOW, I can say.

I can get a private teacher, but I want to try and learn something myself a little before getting one.

What are your suggestions? where can I learn mathematics such as caculus, online?
Thank you a lot.

Comment: Consider coursera.org for a lot of possible options...

Comment: Probably of interest to you are these questions [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543302/what-areas-of-mathematics-are-taught-in-a-computer-engineering-course), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423915/books-for-a-beginner). I reitirate: read [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-Structured-Daniel-Velleman/dp/0521675995), by [D.J. Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/).

Comment: KhanAcademy is the place to go if you want to learn things from scratch but the internet is a wide place with more amazing and fantastic resources. Here's a nick of the surface - https://sites.google.com/site/scienceandmathguide/

Answer (score 1):

I'd try [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) or [EdX](https://www.edx.org/).  I can speak more on behalf of coursera having used it more myself, but both provide free online courses in math, science, and many other areas at levels varying from high school to undergraduate, and in some cases higher.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/). It uses gamification which makes it a little more fun and it covers all basic maths. I would also recommend starting right at the beginning ie. $1+1=2$. You will sail through the easier skills but you will start hitting difficulties much sooner than you expected. The skills that you first start finding a little tricky are the skills that you need to master before continuing. Personally, despite passing advanced university maths courses I still had trouble with things like inequalities and logarithms because I never grasped them in school.